# AngularJS - Extremely slow response-time when submitting a form with $http.POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, forms, post

I have very little experience with Angular and right now I'm having trouble with sending a POST-request after submitting a basic HTML-form with ng-submit(). The post-request goes to a Node.js-server, and the response-time is extremely slow when using the http-service. The code that must be faulty is in the scope.submitMeeting()-function. It fires a method from the meetingService (addMeeting).

```
var app = angular.module('meetingApp', []);

app.service('meetingService', function($http) {
  this.getNewData = function(date) {
    return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/meetings/date/' + date
    })
  }
  this.addMeeting = function(formData) {
    return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      url: '/meetings'
    })
  }
});

app.controller('adminCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $path, meetingService){
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/meetings/date/' + getToday()
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.meetings = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(error) {
    alert(error.statusText);
  });

  var formData = [];

  $scope.submitMeeting = function(formData) {
    formdata = $scope.form;
    meetingService.addMeeting(formdata).then(function successCallback(response) {
      alert('You have added a meeting!');
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
      alert(error.statusText + ': Something went terribly wrong!');
    });
  }

  $scope.dateSearch = getToday();
  $scope.submitSearch = function() {
    meetingService.getNewData($scope.dateSearch).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.meetings = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
      alert(error.statusText);
    });
  }
});
```

As far as I can tell there's nothing wrong here. My back-end seems to be working alright when testing with Postman as well. Here's the form for reference:

```
<form ng-submit="submitMeeting()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Dato</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Velg dato" name="date" ng-model="form.date" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Klokkeslett</label>
            <div id="timeSelect">
              <select name="time" ng-model="form.time" required>
                <option>08</option>
                <option>09</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>11</option>
                <option>12</option>
                <option>13</option>
                <option>14</option>
                <option>15</option>
                <option>16</option>
                <option>17</option>
                <option>18</option>
                <option>19</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>21</option>
                <option>22</option>
                <option>23</option>
                <option>00</option>
                <option>01</option>
                <option>02</option>
                <option>03</option>
                <option>04</option>
                <option>05</option>
                <option>06</option>
                <option>07</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Firma</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv inn firma" name="company" ng-model="form.company" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Gjest</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv inn gjest" ng-model="form.guest" name="guest">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleSelect2">Møterom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv inn møterom/sted" ng-model="form.room" name="room" required>
          </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tilbake</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Legg til</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: What response time do you get if you check it from the network tab in the developer console?

Comment: What do you see with the network panel on your debugger?

Comment: @epascarello It takes literally forever. Both status and time is set to "pending" in the console. The last time I could see a response there, the time-field was simply left with "---". Only once in a while does my back-end receive the request (unless I refresh the page)

Comment: @AnthonyC It took 2.8 minutes now, and the response-status is (failed). It's caught by my error-handler in the callback-function, but the form is still submitted to the server, so I can retrieve the data on the clientside upon refreshing.

Comment: If you are seeing the post request in the network tab, it is unlikely that something in the JavaScript is delaying the response. At that point it must be a problem on the server side. What is in the `formData` parameter passed to `addMeeting`? Is it possible that you are sending something in there that is causing an issue on the server?

Comment: @JackA. I have pasted my form onto the OP. Nevermind the horrenduous select-time input-field, it's just something I put together in a few sec without looking up the proper way to input time.

Comment: @user4612744, can you look at the request data or the request size from the network tab as well?

Comment: @AnthonyC Yes, I can. :)

Comment: Could you please provide some info like status code in your response, response time, and please check if your initial request is stalled in timing section of network tab in dev console so that we could decide if it really is angular issue or some other.

Comment: @Pramod_Para See comments above.

Comment: The possibility of angular being the reason is very low, I think you should debug on the server side once.

Comment: @Pramod_Para Sorry, you were absolutely right. I was missing a response-statement on the server-side. I have no idea how it was not there to begin with.

Comment: Haha, no problemo. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Pramod_Para Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a server-side error like many of you predicted. I was missing a res.json()-statement, so there was no response being returned from the POST-route back to the client.